# How can I create a View in Oracle with a column whose content depends on the combined values of pertaining entities?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, select, plsql

In a Java application based on an Oracle SQL database, I have the following problem to solve:

An entity `DataDelivery` can consist of any number of `Packet`. 
`Packet` has a `PacketStatus` and the the foreign key `datadeliveryid`.

`PacketStatus` is an Enum with the values:

```
0, processed
1, processing
2, error
3, waiting
```

The numeric value is stored in the column `PacketStatus` in table PACKET.

In my view, I want to display the `DataDelivery` as table rows including a column that displays the combined status of all pertaining packets. The combined status of the Packets shall be determined according to the logic below:

- If any one Packet pertaining to a DataDelivery has the status 'error': View column shall display 'error'.
- If any one Packet pertaining to a DataDelivery has the status 'waiting': View column shall display 'waiting'.
- If all Packets pertaining to a DataDelivery have the status 'processed': View column shall display 'processed'.
- If all Packets pertaining to a DataDelivery have the status 'processing': View column shall display 'processing'.
- If all Packets pertaining to a DataDelivery have either the status 'processed' or 'processing': View column shall display 'processing'.

In all other cases the view column shall display: 'error'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` ignores `null`s. You can use this fact to perform a `count` over a `case` expression to count how many of the packets are in which status. From there on, it's a matter of gluing everything together with `case`s:

```sql
SELECT dd.*, status
FROM   DataDelivery dd
JOIN   (SELECT   dataDeliveryId,
                 CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE status WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'error'
                      WHEN COUNT(CASE status WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'waiting'
                      WHEN COUNT(CASE status WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*) THEN 'processed'

                      WHEN COUNT(CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*) THEN 'processing'
                ELSE 'error' END AS status
        FROM     packet
        GROUP BY dataDeliveryId) p ON dd.dataDeliveryId = p.dataDeliveryId
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it worked immediately. Instead of creating a view which would involve many other changes in my code, I'm thinking that there may be an easier solution, such as a virtual column or maybe by using  `@Formula` annotation in the entity DataDelivery. Do you think it is worth investigating?